# T-SQL Select one row for multiple groups from one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:
`NUMBER |    DATE    | VALUE_1 | VALUE_2`
`145789 | 2016-10-01 | A       | Carrot`
`145789 | 2016-10-03 | B       | Apple`
`145789 | 2016-10-14 | C       | Banana`
`748596 | 2016-10-07 | Mango   | Watermelon`
`748596 | 2016-10-19 | Pear    | Strawberry`
`748596 | 2016-10-30 | Orange  | Avocado`

I want to select the first record for each number (the record with the minimum date).
How can I have a result like this?
`NUMBER |    DATE    | VALUE_A | VALUE_B`
`145789 | 2016-10-01 | A       | Carrot`
`748596 | 2016-10-07 | Mango   | Watermelon`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple. You need to use `row_number()` for this, like below. Below we have generated unique numbers(Using Row_number) for each Number group rows based on date. On top of it we have selected only minimum date record (By using where clause ). For More about `row_number` [click here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
 SELECT [NUMBER], [DATE], [VALUE_1], [VALUE_2]
    FROM 
    (

    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NUMBER ORDER BY DATE ASC) RNO
    FROM TABLE1)A
    WHERE RNO=1
```

Comment: It would be nice to see an explanation of what row_number is (window/analytic function) and why it has to be a sub-select to limit to 1 row each.. (or a link to window functions)